# What is and examples of using data type - References

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

i wanted to know about the data type **references** and some examples of how/why it would be used on a website. If their is a difference when using Ruby-on-Rails, i tagged it just in case. I am new at programming and it would help tremendously to explain everything in [layman's terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layman%22Layman%27s%20terms%22) so i can slowly build my way up to being a computer wiz.

Appreciate the trouble in helping me, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm taking a guess that you're referring to `t.references :associated_model` in a migration?

Suppose two models, Post and Author.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Your migration contains:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.references :author
end
```

This will create the `author_id` column on the `posts` table with the `integer` datatype.

In migrations, `t.belongs_to` is an alias for `t.references` and matches the naming used to set up the associations in your models.

Comment: Why would you use this? Isn't it better to use t.integer author_id in the Author model? It seems like the same thing just references is like a ghost.

Comment: It's just sugar to better map the migration terminology to your web application. To someone who groks SQL, it may seem like an unnecessary abstraction.

Answer (score 6):

It is not a real datatype, it is the rails shorthand for creating a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in the table, which is by default an integer.

When you call `t.references :widgets` in your migration, it actually creates an integer column called `widget_id`

You may want to read through the [Rails Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) to learn more about how database and migrations are handled in rails.