# SET data type in mysql with active record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to use the SET data type from mysql in a rails app. However, I don't find it in the list of supported data types or [here](http://niugrad.blogspot.in/2008/03/ruby-rails-column-type-to-mysql.html). Is it a supported data type, and if yes how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No SET is not supported datatype in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [alternative](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2826795) and [try](http://ionrails.com/2010/06/16/set-data-type-mysql-activerecord/) this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The SET data type is **not supported** by Rails

The list of available datatypes in Rails is listed in this Stackoverflow answer:

[Rails 4: List of available datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-list-of-available-datatypes)

there is a gem which try to work around this:

https://github.com/iangreenleaf/native_enum  (I have not used this)