# Rails 3: migration error when using json as a column type in an ActiveRecord backed by Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am running Rails 3.2.17 and Postgres 9.3.4. I created a new ActiveRecord model using "rails generate" and one of the column types is json. My intention is to use the json column type in Postgres.

The db migration contains this code:

```
class CreateThing < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :things do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.json :json_data
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :things, :user_id
  end
end
```

When I try to migrate with "rake db:migrate" I get this error:

```
-- create_table(:things)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `json' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x007fea3d465af8>/Users/../db/migrate/20140425030855_create_things.rb:7:in `block in change'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
```

Is this the right way to add a json column to an ActiveRecord? I cannot find any documentation or examples. Thanks!

Comment: Try giving like this `t.column :json_data, :json`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change your migration like

```
class CreateThing < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :things do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.column :json_data, :json   # Edited
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :things, :user_id
  end
end
```

And by default `rake db` tasks will look into schema.rb( which wont be the case for postgres) so in application.rb change it to

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the following in application.rb

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Then structure.sql will be used instead of schema.rb to create the database from scratch. More info - https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Answer (score 0):

We have a legacy application that uses [`activerecord-postgres-json`](https://github.com/romanbsd/activerecord-postgres-json) to add `json` and `jsonb` type support to ActiveRecord in Rails 3.2; it may be an option if you're stuck at a low Rails version.