# Getting error - type "json" does not exist - in Postgresql during rake db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

I have recently cloned a project to my local Ubuntu box now that I am remote, and upon rake db migrate, I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "json" does not exist
```

A couple columns in my tables that are:

```
add_column :table, :column, :json
```

This migration works on the Macs at work, but are not working here. I have tried upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.3.4, but the issue still persists. I also tried sudo apt-get upgrade postgresql, and still the problem persists.

Ruby version is 2.1.0
Rails version is 4.0.3

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284164/rails-3-migration-error-when-using-json-as-a-column-type-in-an-activerecord-bac

Comment: No. But the solution from that problem is how I have the schema currently set up. I also tried modifying application.rb as shown in the answers to no avail.

Comment: The `json` data type was introduced with Postgres 9.2. It should definitely work with v9.3.1. You did not disclose the *actual* version of the Postgres db cluster you are connecting to. What do you get for `SELECT version()`?

Comment: After upgrading PostgreSQL try to update the PG gem. Not sure if it can help but you could give it a try

Comment: Yes. So the command shows that 9.1 is online and 9.3 is down. Currently looking how to remedy that. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I have tried upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.3.4, but the issue still persists

Most likely you're still connecting to the old version. Try `SELECT version()`.

Since you mention `apt-get` you're presumably on Debian or Ubuntu. These use `pg_wrapper` to allow multiple PostgreSQL installs in parallel. Each one gets a different port number. The first install gets the default port 5432. Subsequent installs get higher ports.

You can view the installs with `pg_lsclusters`. Most likely your 9.3 install is on port 9433, and you need to change your `database.yml` (since you're using Rails) to connect to that port.

Comment: Actually, yes this helped me understand that 9.1 was online and not 9.3. 9.3 was down.

Answer (score 5):

If for any reason you run into this issue, your 9.3 version is not actually running.

I found this link to very helpful:

http://nixmash.com/postgresql/upgrading-postgresql-9-1-to-9-3-in-ubuntu/

I started with the command:

```
sudo service postgresql stop
```

and ran all the commands from there. Everything works fine now.

Comment: For ubuntu 12.04 LTS - https://gist.github.com/mdpatrick/8895813 for upgrading from 9.1 to 9.3