# Rails migration Documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Really simple question but struggling to find complete API documentation for Rails Active Record migrations.

Anyone know the best place to get a list (apart from source code)

e.g. found example of using arrays in rails 4, but cannot find in docs

```
class AddEmailsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :emails, :string, array: true, default: '{}'
  end
end
```

e.g. at
https://coderwall.com/p/sud9ja

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-datatypes

Comment: great that answered it, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not what you are looking for exactly, but here is the github pull request for rails support of arrays in migration:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7547

*PostgreSQL array type support. Any datatype can be used to create an array column, with full migration and schema dumper support.
To declare an array column, use the following syntax:*

```
create_table :table_with_arrays do |t|
  t.integer :int_array, :array => true
  # integer[]
  t.integer :int_array, :array => true, :length => 2
  # smallint[]
  t.string :string_array, :array => true, :length => 30
  # char varying(30)[]
end
```

*This respects any other migraion detail (limits, defaults, etc). ActiveRecord will serialize and deserialize the array columns on their way to and from the database.
One thing to note: PostgreSQL does not enforce any limits on the number of elements, and any array can be multi-dimensional. Any array that is multi-dimensional must be rectangular (each sub array must have the same number of elements as its siblings).*

And an edge guide:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

```
# db/migrate/20140207133952_create_books.rb
create_table :books do |t|
  t.string 'title'
  t.string 'tags', array: true
  t.integer 'ratings', array: true
end
add_index :books, :tags, using: 'gin'
add_index :books, :ratings, using: 'gin'

# app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# Usage
Book.create title: "Brave New World",
            tags: ["fantasy", "fiction"],
            ratings: [4, 5]

## Books for a single tag
Book.where("'fantasy' = ANY (tags)")

## Books for multiple tags
Book.where("tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["fantasy", "fiction"])

## Books with 3 or more ratings
Book.where("array_length(ratings, 1) >= 3")
```