# Is there a Char(character) datatype in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use the smallest data types possible for every attribute used in each model.

for example I have a Sauce model which I want to have used filter by attributes like: hot_or_not: boolean, name:string,

but also i was thinking of allowing users to filter by origin as in Mexican, Indian, Chinese, Korean, Caribbean etc. but since these will be a small number of possible origin categories I want to be able to store it using only one byte.

Like maybe each of these origins will be a value of a Char key like I => India. And in the database only store the Char key.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
t.string :name, :limit => 1, :null => false
```

Comment: just to clarify, does this modify the space allocated within the database, or just limit the amount of characters it takes in. For example when you set limit to one, does it just create a 1 byte space to hold the character, or is it still a giant string space?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct `char` type in ActiveRecord. The closest is `string` which maps to `varchar` in most database backends. It'll use a little more space but generally it won't be an issue.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-datatypes) has a list of the data types available and their mappings in various DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use like this in your migration file.

```
t.string :column_name, limit: 10
```

Comment: could I also create 3 identifier boolean columns that I could later use to identify an 'origin' like Indian => boolean1: True, boolean2: False, boolean3: False. And Mexican => boolean1: True, boolean2: True, boolean3: False? Something like that? then it would only take 3 bits right?

Comment: It will take 3 bytes.