# How do I update a sequence in Rails and get the resulting value in my object?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sequence

Say I have a class derived from ActiveRecord. It has several fields, plus an "id" field. The "id" is created so it's default value is the "nextval" of a sequence so it auto-increments every time a new record is saved. It was created by doing:

`CREATE SEQUENCE id_sequence;`

`ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('id_sequence');`

So, now in Ruby, I populate the fields in my object, and then I "save!" it. Now I need to do some more work with the object but the "id" field is still set to nil. There is no "load" function in Ruby that will let me reload the object from the DB. And despite what you would think, the "!" in ActiveRecord does NOT mean it modifies the original object (What is the point of Ruby conventions if Rails does not follow them). It doesn't seem you can do "self.find_by" within the original object. The only think I can think of doing is calling "find_by" on some defining message field of the table (which is near impossible because that is what the id is for but I don't have it yet!) and create a new object and getting the id out of that.

There must be some easier way.

Comment: so you're saying calling `save!` doesn't raise an error? what does `save` return?

Comment: I've never heard of a "serial" column and it doesn't seem like one of the ActiveRecord datatypes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-datatypes

Comment: It seems like the answer so far is to use "reload' after calling "save". This is at least better than the hack I was doing before.

Answer (score 1):

Rails ActiveRecord is supposed to update the object automatically with its new id when it is created. This normally works fine when the sequence and the column are created at the same time, e.g. using the SERIAL type. Merely setting the default value of a column to `nextval(sequence_name)` is not enough to "bind" the sequence to the column.

The solution would seem to be to associating the sequence with the column by setting its ownership, like this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE id_sequence OWNED BY my_table.id;
```

This should allow ActiveRecord to query the pg catalog and find the correct sequence value to retrieve.

You can check this by running `SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table', 'id')` before and after the alter statement. Before it will likely be blank, and after it should show the sequence name ( `id_sequence` in your example). This is the query ActiveRecord runs to find the name of the appropriate sequence [(line 258 in schema_statements.rb)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4b560bf96b1c48bc996c8e7d03d42c4353c3b1bf/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb).

If that still doesn't work I would rename the sequence to the convention: `tablename_columnname_seq` -- so  `my_table_id_seq` in your case.

Comment: Actually I did have a "ALTER SEQUENCE id_sequence OWNED BY my_table.id". When I create the object and "save" it, I look in the database and I see that the "id" is set to the correct number and the sequence is incremented so I know the db side of things is working. But when I look at the object, the id is set to be "nil". If I then create a new object and "find_by" to get the object I just created the id will be set but this is awkward and only works if I can load the object using some other identifying field.

Comment: @Mike Create a new table with a SERIAL column and see if that works.

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't see that. Then it should be working because, AFAIK, AR will using `INSERT ... RETURNING id` to create the new entry. Unless perhaps `id` is somehow not the PK.