# Rails migration error - table not showing in schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, rake, database-migration

One of my model tables (Event) is not showing in the schema.rb file and in its place there is this message -

```
# Could not dump table "events" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The last migration that was succesful was as follows -

```
class RemoveOrganiserDescriptionFromEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :events, :organiser_description, :text
  end
end
```

Which was changed to this -

```
class AddOrganiserProfileToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :organiser_profile, :url
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure its gone 'wonky' because the attribute shouldn't be a url it should be a string. However, when I try to perform other migrations it doesn't work. I get the following error in my terminal when I try and perform a rake db:migrate -

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  to_s/Users/Michael/MWCoding/MamaKnows/mama_knows/db/migrate/20160415123947_remove_events_organiser_profile.rb:3:in`change'
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  to_s

In my migration files this was my code -

```
def change
   change_column :events, :organiser_profile :string

end

def up
  change_column :events, :organiser_profile, :string
end

def down
  change_column :events, :organiser_profile, :url
end
```

I've also tried to remove the column completely in an attempt to then replace it with the correct version but to no avail. All impending help would be appreciated.

Comment: `remove_column :events, :organiser_description` - **RemoveOrganiserDescriptionFromEvents** should look like this. try changing this

Comment: why do you have change, up and down in migration?

Comment: I saw it on a previous SO Q&A.

Comment: I've tried the above and it hasn't worked.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead not sure what you are trying to achieve here. If you would have run the migration **AddOrganiserProfileToEvents**, it will not run since `url` is not a datatype.

Comment: That migration went through - see below output from my command line.

Comment: rails g migration add_organiser_profile_to_events organiser_profile:url
Running via Spring preloader in process 25270
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160414170327_add_organiser_profile_to_events.rb
➜  Mama_Knows git:(Migrations) ✗ rake db:migrate
== 20160414170327 AddOrganiserProfileToEvents: migrating ======================
-- add_column(:events, :organiser_profile, :url)
   -> 0.0007s
== 20160414170327 AddOrganiserProfileToEvents: migrated (0.0007s) =============

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by dropping the migrations and re-migrating:

rake db:drop:all

then

rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

```
add_column :events, :organiser_profile, :url
```

does not make sense. See the documentation for `add_column` method [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column). The parameters are table, column name and column type. `:url` is not a valid type. Valid types are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25702629/908842)

Comment: The migration went through (see above) but this is obviously what has broken it. Question is, how do I get it back??

Comment: Remove offending migration .rb files and then do "rake db:drop" and then "rake db:migrate"

Comment: So, its that particular migration file that I need to get rid of? Do I just delete it from my file or do I delete it on the command line?

Comment: Just delete the file and rerun migrations from scratch (see my comment above)

Comment: Won't rake db:drop remove the entire database?

Comment: yes - it will. Why - is that a problem? This is the cleanest way to fix your problem. Otherwise, you can just remove the offending .rb migration files and run rake db:rollback/rake db:migrate

Comment: Yes, I don't want to delete the whole database - I only want to delete the migration file that I incorrectly inputted as this is what appears to be causing the issue.

Comment: Is that the process? delete file / rollback / migrate ?

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations

Comment: Nothing I'm trying is working here. rollback migrate:redo, deleting the file - nothing will let me remove this rogue file from my database. Any other suggestions?