# Mysql2 Error in activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi all getting this error and I think it's appended to this query.

```
ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '? AND `profile_activity`.`entity_type` IN (?, ?, ?, ?)  ORDER BY `profile_activi' at line 1: 

   EXPLAIN SELECT  `profile_activity`.`date_created`, `profile_activity`.`entity_id`, `profile_activity`.`entity_type`, `profile_activity`.`activity_type` 
   FROM `profile_activity` 
   WHERE `profile_activity`.`user_id` = 197056 
       AND `profile_activity`.`activity_type` = ? 
       AND `profile_activity`.`entity_type` IN (?, ?, ?, ?)  
   ORDER BY `profile_activity`.`date_created` DESC 
   LIMIT 19 OFFSET 0
```

Here is the active record query

```
    ProfileActivity
      .select(:date_created, :entity_id, :entity_type, :activity_type)
      .where(activity_type: 'V', entity_type: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'WL'])
      .order(date_created: :desc)
      .limit(limit)
      .offset(offset)
```

It looks like it does not interpret the first string 'V' and so forth. Not sure why this is happening. Thanks for any help with this.

The database columns are CHARS for entity_type and activity_type.

EDIT***

profile activity model

```
class ProfileActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'profile_activity'

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :agency, foreign_key: :agency_id, primary_key: :entity_id
  has_one :company, foreign_key: :company_id, primary_key: :entity_id
  has_one :company_brand, foreign_key: :brand_id, primary_key: :entity_id

  scope :views, -> (limit, offset) {
  select(:date_created, :entity_id, :entity_type, :activity_type).where(activity_type: 'V', entity_type: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'WL']).order(date_created: :desc).limit(limit).offset(offset)
  }

  scope :most_recent_views_by_user, -> (user_id) {
    sql        = ProfileActivity.where(user_id: user_id).to_sql
    table_name = ProfileActivity.table_name
    select(:date_created, :entity_id, :entity_type, :activity_type)
.where(activity_type: 'V', entity_type: ['A', 'B', 'C'])
.order(date_created: :desc).limit(10)
.from("(#{sql}) as #{table_name}")
    }
end
```

my_activity_controller.rb

```
def user_activities
activities = []

if current_user
  decoder        = HTMLEntities.new
  activity_views = ProfileActivity.where(user_id: current_user.id).views(params[:limit], params[:offset])

  activity_views.each do |a|
    next if (a.created_at.nil? || a.entity_id == 0)

    begin
      case a.entity_type
      when 'B'
        business            = Business.find_by(id: a.entity_id)
        entity_name         = decoder.decode(business.name)
        entity_type         = 'Business'
        entity_abbreviation = 'B'
      else
        entity_name = nil
        entity_type = nil
      end

      case a.activity_type
      when 'D'
        activity_type = 'downloaded'
      when 'P'
        activity_type = 'printed'
      when 'V'
        activity_type = 'viewed'
      else
        activity_type = nil
      end

      case a.entity_type
      when 'B'
        url = business_profile_path(a.entity_id)
      else
        url = nil
      end

      activities << { date:                a.created_at,
                      url:                 url,
                      entity_name:         entity_name,
                      entity_type:         entity_type,
                      entity_abbreviation: entity_abbreviation,
                      activity_type:       activity_type }
    rescue => e
      ErrorHandler.notify_exception(e, env: env) rescue nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you also add migration file that created this `profile_activity` table?

Comment: Also your `ProfileActivity` model file?

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura thank you! I edited the question above with the profile activtity model. But unfortunately that table was leftover from a legacy app. I  have access to the table if you need some other info from it.

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura the encoding and collation for entity_type and activity_type are cp1252 and latin respectively. Do you think that might be the issue? I know most of our encoding is UTF and utf unicode in our database.

Comment: I'm not sure if encoding could be the issue. However, I would suggest you try the answer I posted and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

> > This answer is for Rails version 4.2

My best guess is that ActiveRecord is failing to recognize the type of the `entity_type` and `activity_type`. This is because, ActiveRecord doesn't support CHAR data types. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17918118/976880

You could explicitly specify the type of those columns on your model like this:

```
class ProfileActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'profile_activity'

  attribute :entity_type, ActiveRecord::Type::String.new
  attribute :activity_type, ActiveRecord::Type::String.new
  ...
end
```

This way ActiveRecord considers them as Strings and generates the proper query.

**EDIT**

If the column type being `CHAR` is not a requirement, you could add a migration to change it to `VARCHAR` instead of doing the above.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think another possibility is to do a migration and convert these columns to VARCHAR?

Comment: @Chris however, have you tried the solution I gave?  it worked? Would be interesting to know for me and those would will see this question later.

Comment: I'm going to implement but have to wait until this gets into production. Locally I can't get the error to display it only comes up in production. I'll let you know and mark your answer as soon as I get confirmation. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Getting this error now uninitialized constant User::ProfileActivity</p>
            <pre style="font-size: 12px; padding: 5px; background-color:#f5f5f5">
app/controllers/hubignite/api/my_activity_controller.rb:97:in `user_activities&#39;
            </pre>

Comment: added the file above, i ended up using the attributes because doing the migration would take too long because the table is too large. But now getting this error with user, I'm guessing because it belongs_to user. How could I fix this type of error?

Comment: Whereever you were calling ProfileActivity, prepend `::` to it like `::ProfileActivity`. Also, try the query in `rails console` before your actually put it into the controller somewhere.

Comment: Also, what is line 97 in your controller that is raising the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118330/discussion-between-chris-and-abadasscowboy).