# What validations to use for an array data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql

PostgreSQL adds other data types to the Active Record default. 
See [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype.html), [List of available datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-list-of-available-datatypes#17918118) at Stackoverflow and [Active Record and PostgreSQL](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) at RailsGuides. 
For the `array` data type it is necessary to add `array: true` in the migration. For instance:

```
create_table :books do |t|
  t.string 'title'
  t.string 'tags', array: true
  t.integer 'ratings', array: true
end
```

What kind of validations should be used in the Book model? 
If integer was a non-array data type I would use:

```
validates :ratings, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
```

Would this validation be correct also in case `ratings` is an array data type? 
I am interested in validating the array elements not the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built in validation for such case.

You could write custom one:

```
validate :valid_ratings

private

def valid_ratings
  if everything_is_ok
    true
  else
    errors.add(:ratings, 'ratings is invalid') if something_is_wrong
  end
end
```