# Using group_by beginning_of_month, how do I get an event to show again in the next month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*Using Rails 5.0.2*

I have a bunch of events, grouped by month that looks like this:

---

### **April**

**Event 1**

*23 April - 24 April*

**Event 2**

*28 April - 22 June*

---

### **May**

**Event 3**

*4 May - 5 May*

---

The problem is, some events go for ages! E.g. Event 2 starts 23 April but finishes 22 June.

How would I get the event item to show up again in the next month(s)?

Current working code:

**Controller:**

```
@monthly = @events.group_by { |t| t.start_date.beginning_of_month }
```

**Index view:**

```
<% @monthly.sort.each do |month, event| %>
  <h2><%= month.strftime('%B') %></h2>

    <% for event in event %>

      <li><%= event.title %></li>
      <%= event.start_date %>
      <%= event.end_date %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks ya'll!

Comment: Instead of grouping each event by the month of the event's `start_date`, you should iterate from January to December and show each event that occurs within that month (see [`Range#overlaps?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Range.html#method-i-overlaps-3F)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could take is to *first* define the list of all months in the range to be displayed, and then associate all events with that month.

You may wish to tweak the code below for your needs - e.g. if you don't want to show events in the past, or in the next calendar year:

```
first_start_month = Event.minimum(:start_date).beginning_of_month
last_end_month = Event.maximum(:end_date).beginning_of_month

months = [first_start_date]
while(months.last != last_end_month) do
  months << months.last + 1.month
end

@monthly_events = months.map do |m|
  [m, @events.select { |e| (e.start_date .. e.end_date).include?(m) }]
end.to_h
```

With this, your view code can remain basically unchanged:

```
<% @monthly_events.each do |month, events| %>
  <h2><%= month.strftime('%B') %></h2>

    <% events.each do |event| %>

      <li><%= event.title %></li>
      <%= event.start_date %>
      <%= event.end_date %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Good approach though the complexity is always O(mn) whereas my solution is O(mn) only in the worst case but tends towards O(n).

Comment: The flexibility of being able to easily change the `first_start_month` and `last_end_month` is why I'd be inclined to use my solution. Sometimes it's worth trading off a tiny performance gain in favour of more easily readable/manipulable code :)

Comment: Hey @tom, thanks for your help - I'm getting a bad value for range error on this line here `[m, @events.select { |e| (e.start_date .. e.end_date).include?(m) }]`

Comment: nvm, managed to get it working by converting the dates into strings and chopping off the day `e.start_date.to_s[0...-3]` since the dates were stored as 2017-05-21.. not pretty but it works! thanks for your help again!

Comment: If you're looking for a less hacky solution, you could (ideally) store the `start_date` and `end_date` as [date types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17918118/1954610) in the database. Or, failing that, use [`Date#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) to work with `Date` objects rather than strings.