# Can a Rails attribute be an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently learned about the `json` datatype in Rails 5, which allows you to store a hash in a PostgreSQL database. For some reason I can't find a full list of Rails 5 datatypes. Is there any sort of datatype that similarly allows you to store an array?

Such that `example_record.array_datatype => ["1", "2", "3"]`

Comment: *"For some reason I can't find a full list of Rails 5 datatypes"* -- Really?? [This is the first result from a google search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17918118/1954610).

Comment: And [here is the full list](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2b96d5822bfe407be7589e293f3265c0c7a6726c/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L73-L114) of supported datatypes in rails 5, as of today.

Comment: You can also check [rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array)

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for the updated list, I saw that Google result but it's an incomplete list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed. Here is a sample migration to add an integer and a string array to a model:

```
class AddToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :books, :category_ids, :integer, array: true, default: [], null: false
    add_column :books, :subjects    , :text   , array: true, default: [], null: false
  end
end
```

For arrays of strings, use `:text` as the type.

I'd strongly recommend using an empty array instead of a null to indicate "no data", and this migration ensures that.

Comment: What does `null: false` do? It makes empty arrays instead of null ones?

Comment: @JoeMorano It adds a database constraint. As with your original question, google is your friend.

Comment: Yes, it means that you cannot store a null in that column.