# Can't create file field with ActiveStorage in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to use Active Storage in Rails 5.2. I found that I should create field with type `file` in migration, but I have an error:

```
$ rdm
Running via Spring preloader in process 40193
== 20171217191942 CreateDishes: migrating 
=====================================
-- create_table(:dishes)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `file' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x00007fd56e297750>
/Users/alder/Projects/_apps/service_exchange/rails-backend/db/migrate/20171217191942_create_dishes.rb:6:in `block in change'
/Users/alder/Projects/_apps/service_exchange/rails-backend/db/migrate/20171217191942_create_dishes.rb:3:in `change'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

Migration:

```
class CreateDishes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :dishes do |t|
      t.string :name, index: true
      t.string :description
      t.file :image

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I was trying to create string field, but it doesn't work.

Couldn't find anything about that in [official docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)

I have migration for active storage and I passed ok

Comment: i'm pretty sure there's no such data type 'file' in rails migration, try using f.string

Comment: Check this blog: https://rubyinrails.com/2017/07/21/rails-introduces-active-storage-for-file-uploads/

Comment: So, yeah, I used exactly that link. If you make string field it shows type mismatch later.

Comment: what class is the migration inheriting from? Ensure it's the latest migration version to pick up on new column types within ActiveRecord, `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of a dedicated field that you need to create in your own migration (`t.file :image`) active storage uses two tables that you [setup](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup) with  `rails active_storage:install`.
When you setup your storage.yml you should be able to use

```
has_one_attached :image
```

within the `Dishes`model without creating a `image`column.

Comment: I thought that probably I shouldn't create any field for image, I'll check it later, but I guess It's correct answer.

Comment: I'm having issues with using `:avatar` as the name of the data field, could this be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can check this question [(ActiveRecord field type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-list-of-available-datatypes) because did not have any type like `file` if you need to upload a file you can create with type `string` like `t.string`