# How to get Ruby type from PostgreSQL type using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I do MyClass.columns the columns will have a type attribute with values like :integer, :string, :datetime, etc.  How can I take that type and map it to the ruby type?

For example:

:integer => Integer

:string => String

:datetime => DateTime

I assume Rails has a canonical lookup list that I could use but I can't seem to find it.  Ideally, I would find a way that works for every DB adapter that Rails supports.

Comment: this link probably good answer for your question above https://stackoverflow.com/a/17918118/938947

Comment: That provides the type => Postgres Type mapping.  I am looking for the type => Ruby type mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "type matches" for PostgreSQL [in the source code on the official repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb).

```
NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES = {
        primary_key: "bigserial primary key",
        string:      { name: "character varying" },
        text:        { name: "text" },
        integer:     { name: "integer", limit: 4 },
        float:       { name: "float" },
        decimal:     { name: "decimal" },
        datetime:    { name: "timestamp" },
        time:        { name: "time" },
        date:        { name: "date" },
        daterange:   { name: "daterange" },
        numrange:    { name: "numrange" },
        tsrange:     { name: "tsrange" },
        tstzrange:   { name: "tstzrange" },
        int4range:   { name: "int4range" },
        int8range:   { name: "int8range" },
        binary:      { name: "bytea" },
        boolean:     { name: "boolean" },
        xml:         { name: "xml" },
        tsvector:    { name: "tsvector" },
        hstore:      { name: "hstore" },
        inet:        { name: "inet" },
        cidr:        { name: "cidr" },
        macaddr:     { name: "macaddr" },
        uuid:        { name: "uuid" },
        json:        { name: "json" },
        jsonb:       { name: "jsonb" },
        ltree:       { name: "ltree" },
        citext:      { name: "citext" },
        point:       { name: "point" },
        line:        { name: "line" },
        lseg:        { name: "lseg" },
        box:         { name: "box" },
        path:        { name: "path" },
        polygon:     { name: "polygon" },
        circle:      { name: "circle" },
        bit:         { name: "bit" },
        bit_varying: { name: "bit varying" },
        money:       { name: "money" },
        interval:    { name: "interval" },
        oid:         { name: "oid" },
}
```

I would add that it is indeed good to know how things work under the hood, one of the goals of the ORM is for you to not having to care about that. You are supposed to use your ruby data types in your migrations.

If you want to have a *cross-database* solution, just avoid to use types that are not matched to the same on each DBMS (like `:decimal`)

Comment: That is the Postgres type.  I'm looking for the Ruby type.